# unexpected behavior of a c program, trying to solve E6-2 K&R

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

**Exercise 6-2.** Write a program that reads a C program and prints in alphabetical order each group of
variable names that are identical in the first 6 characters, but different somewhere thereafter. Don't count
words within strings and comments. Make 6 a parameter that can be set from the command line. (from K&R)

I started working on the exercise, and I'm stuck on the beginning. I tried to get the whole input and save it line by line in an array, and then point pointers in an array to the saved line. Later I thought of allocating space for each word and coppy them to a tree. However, in the following code when I'm typing as an input:

> abc def;'Ctrl-Z'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 100
#define MAXWORDS 10

int read_input(char *[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *variables[MAXWORDS] = {0};
    int i;
    int tmp;


    while((tmp = read_input(variables)) != EOF){
        for(i=0; i < tmp; i++){
            printf("%s ",*(variables+i));
        }
    }


    return 0;
}


/* read_input: mapping all the input words into *variables[], and returning the number of the words + 1 */
int read_input(char *variables[]){
    static char s[MAXLINE];
    int tmp;
    int i, j;

    i = 0;
    if((tmp = getline(s, MAXLINE)) == EOF)
        return EOF;

    for(j = 0; j < MAXWORDS && s[i] != '\0'; j++){ /* it does'nt work when j = MAXWORDS because the rest of the line is not saved */
        while(!isalpha(s[i]))
            i++;
        *(variables+j) = &s[i];
        while(isalnum(s[i]) || s[i] == '_')
            i++;
        if(s[i] == '\0')
            continue;
        s[i++] = '\0';
    }
    return j;
}

/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char *s,int lim)
{
    static char end; /* static typed char that saves if the last not saved 'c' was an EOF */
    char c;
    int i;
    if(end == EOF){ /* the last input character was an EOF */
        end = 0;
        return EOF;
    }
    for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!=';'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if(i > 0 && c == EOF)
        end = EOF;
    else if(i == 0 && c == EOF){
        printf("!");
        return EOF;
    }
    else
        return i;

}
```

the program doesn't stop immediately, and the main's while loop would ask for another input... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is that `abc def;'Ctrl-Z'` ??

Comment: `Ctrl+Z` is most likely not sending EOF signal to the program.

Comment: @RSahu
this is what I typed in input to the program in the cmd, a word, then space, then another word, then ';' and then EOF.
But i dont inderstand why the program doesn's stop though I typed EOF...

Comment: My suggestion: Put the input data in a file. Then, user IO redirection in your command shell while running the program.

Comment: @RSahu
it worked, but i dont understand the problem in the program : )

Comment: Did you need to change the program?

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` must be the first keystroke after `Enter`, and be followed by another `Enter`.

Comment: @RSahu
yes, I tried what Armen(from the answers) showed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line to the beginning of your main function

```
freopen("filename.txt", "r", stdin);
```

it will redirect all your standard input to read from the file. That will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: I have not learned yet about using files, and the function. 
And I really want to know what is the problem with the program because I have misunderstood something with the metirial.

Comment: it worked, but i dont understand the problem in the program : )

Comment: @BarK: There is no problem in the program. The problem is that you're parsing the input until END OF FILE. Where there are no physical files involved, what END OF FILE is is a bit of a headache to understand. So use files.

Comment: @BarK: The CTRL+Z thing works, but only on a separate line

Comment: thank you very much! I couldn't figure out the problem for two days.